# Changing column name in a Hive external table that contains data

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a column insert_process_id that I am trying to rename to process_id. This external table is in parquet file format. Please advise how to rename this column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following syntax

```
ALTER TABLE table_name [PARTITION partition_spec] CHANGE [COLUMN] col_old_name col_new_name column_type
  [COMMENT col_comment] [FIRST|AFTER column_name] [CASCADE|RESTRICT];
```

As this is an external table, you can drop the table and re-create again with specific changes.

Comment: Is this safe to rename an external table with existing parquet file? after renamed the column, I got all nulls for the renamed column.

Answer (score 1):

You can change column name as below.

**Syntax:**

```
ALTER TABLE name CHANGE column_name col_spec ..
```

**Example:**

1. I have created table as below.

   ```
   CREATE EXTERNAL Table IF NOT EXISTS Patient_external(
   PatientID int, Name String, City String, Number String )
   COMMENT 'Data about patient from Apollo Hospital'
   ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
   STORED AS PARQUET 
   LOCATION '/user/training/external/data' ;
   ```
2. Loaded data into table

   ```
   LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 
   '/home/cloudera/Desktop/HiveTraining/Dataset/patient_details' INTO TABLE Patient_external;
   ```
3. Describe the table

   ```
   describe formatted Patient_external;



   col_name                data_type               comment             

   **patientid**               int                                         
   name                    string                                      
   city                    string                                      
   number                  string                                      

   Detailed Table Information       
    Database:              default                  
    Owner:                 cloudera                 
    CreateTime:            Mon Mar 25 10:57:23 PDT 2019     
    LastAccessTime:        UNKNOWN                  
    Protect Mode:          None                     
    Retention:             0                        
    Location:          
     hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/training/external/data    
    Table Type:            EXTERNAL_TABLE           
    Table Parameters:       
           COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE   false               
           EXTERNAL                TRUE                
           comment                 Data about patient from Apollo Hospital
           numFiles                0                   
          numRows              -1                  
          rawDataSize          -1                  
        totalSize              0                   
   transient_lastDdlTime   1553536643          

     Storage Information        
        SerDe Library:          
         org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe    
        InputFormat:            
             org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat  
        OutputFormat:           
            org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat
   ```
4. Change the column name from PatientID to Patient_ID

   ```
        Alter Table Patient_external change PatientID Patient_ID Int;
   ```
5. Now describe the table

   ```
       describe formatted Patient_external;

    col_name               data_type               comment             

   **patient_id**              int                                         
   name                    string                                      
   city                    string                                      
   number                  string                                      

   Detailed Table Information       
    Database:              default                  
    Owner:                 cloudera                 
    CreateTime:            Mon Mar 25 10:57:23 PDT 2019     
    LastAccessTime:        UNKNOWN                  
    Protect Mode:          None                     
    Retention:             0                        
    Location:          
     hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/training/external/data    
    Table Type:            EXTERNAL_TABLE           
    Table Parameters:       
           COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE   false               
           EXTERNAL                TRUE                
           comment                 Data about patient from Apollo Hospital
           numFiles                0                   
          numRows              -1                  
          rawDataSize          -1                  
        totalSize              0                   
   transient_lastDdlTime   1553536643          

     Storage Information        
        SerDe Library:          
         org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe    
        InputFormat:            
             org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat  
        OutputFormat:           
            org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat
   ```

Comment: Is this safe to rename for an external table with existing parquet file? after renamed the column, I got all nulls for the renamed column.

Comment: Why would you 'ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',''?

Answer (score 0):

Parquet uses named based look up. So, metadata based rename renders older data inaccessible. There are two ways to solve this (after renaming)

1. Create a backup for the existing table and insert overwrite existing table by picking older and new column based on a criteria.
2. Create a view and select old and new column based on a criteria (eg: using a partition column value)

The second option avoids having to backfill again and is a recommended option for future schema changes as well.